# Subsetting a reactive object in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am in the process of learning Shiny and developing a simple app.  The start of the program will allow a user to import a CSV file and then apply a filter variable(s) if needed.  They will only be able to use factors as filter variables at this stage.  I apply the filters on an iterative basis.  So, one can apply a filter based on a factor level and then apply another factor level and so on until completed.

The best application I could find of being able to subset a reactive data frame was to apply the data frame as a reactive value.  This seems to work, but I am having a couple issues that I can't figure out how to resolve.

1) Given the filtering is an iterative process, I would like to keep track and print out each variable and level applied during the filtering process.  The best way I could figure out was creating a global variable (<<-) and using renderText to print out the contents after hitting the apply filter button.  The issue is renderText just flashes on the screen and quickly disappears.  I included a print to console statement that verifies the text is being saved correctly.  I believe this is happening from the filter being applied to the reactive data frame and the updating process, but I can't figure out how to stop the text from disappearing on the screen?

2) When I try to save out the reactive data frame at the end of the shiny code, I get the following error "Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". I tried a couple things, but don't really understand what is going on here because the object "file$dfSource" is not like a normal reactive data frame dfSource()?

The shiny app below uses iris data so its easier to use/test.  I don't know if applying the data frame to a reactive value is the best way to program this or if there is an easier way to do all this - just trying to learn best approach here.

```
library(shiny)
allfilters <- c()

ui <- (fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Filter Data"),

# Input Forms
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
    h3("Data"),
        checkboxInput("selectFilter", label = "Apply Filter Variable", value = FALSE),
        uiOutput("selectFilterVar"),
    uiOutput("selectFilterGroup"),
    helpText("Apply filter to data"),
    uiOutput("selectFilterButton"),
    helpText("Reset data to total"),
    uiOutput("selectResetButton"),   
    h3("Download Data"),    
        helpText("Download Data"),
        downloadButton("downloadData", "Download File")
    ),

# Output Forms
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
     tabPanel("Summary",
     h2("Output Summary"),
     textOutput("ncases"),
     textOutput("selectedfilters")))
  )
  )
))

server <- (function(input, output, session) {

data <- iris
file <- reactiveValues(dfSource = data)

## Select Filter Variable
output$selectFilterVar <- renderUI({
       req(file$dfSource)
       if (input$selectFilter){
       selectInput("filterVar", "Select Filter Variable", multiple = FALSE, choices = sort(names(file$dfSource[, sapply(file$dfSource, is.factor), drop = FALSE])))
}         
})         

# Select Filter Group(s)
output$selectFilterGroup <- renderUI({
        req(file$dfSource)
        req(input$filterVar)
        if (input$selectFilter){
        selectInput("filterGroup", "Select Filter Group", multiple = TRUE, choices = sort(unique(file$dfSource[,input$filterVar])))
}
})

# Apply Filter Button
output$selectFilterButton <- renderUI({
         req(file$dfSource)
         if (input$selectFilter) {
          actionButton("filterButton", "Apply Filter")
}
})

# Apply filter group to data
    observeEvent(input$filterButton, {
    temp <- file$dfSource[(file$dfSource[,input$filterVar] %in% c(input$filterGroup)),]
    file$dfSource <- temp
})

# Reset Total Sample Button
output$selectResetButton <- renderUI({
         req(file$dfSource)
         if (input$selectFilter) {
          actionButton("resetButton", "Reset Total")
}
})

# Reset data to total sample
    observeEvent(input$resetButton, {
    file$dfSource <- data
    updateCheckboxInput(session, "selectFilter", value = FALSE)
    allfilters <- NULL
})

## Summary number of cases
output$ncases <- renderText({
  req(file$dfSource)
  mainTitle <- paste("Number of cases =" , nrow(file$dfSource))
  return(mainTitle)  
})

## Capture selected filter variables in global object
testfilter <- eventReactive(input$filterButton, {
     appliedfilter <- paste0(input$filterVar, "(", input$filterGroup,")")
      if (is.null(allfilters)) {
        allfilters <<- paste("Selected Filters:", appliedfilter)
        } else {
        allfilters <<- paste(allfilters, "&", appliedfilter)
   }
   return(allfilters)
   })

# Print out filter variables in global object
output$selectedfilters <- renderText({
    filteroutput <- testfilter()
    print(filteroutput)
    return(filteroutput)
})

## Save out case data file
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
    write.csv(file$dfSource, file)
    }
  )

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Storing it a global variable is probably not a good idea (scope in shiny is already complicated enough!). You already have a `reactiveValues` object, why not use that?

This alone, however, is not enough; the problem seems to be the `eventReactive` - I'm not quite sure why.

This works:

```
# this replaces the testfilter eventReactive
observeEvent(input$filterButton, {
  appliedfilter <- paste0(input$filterVar, "(", input$filterGroup,")")
  if (is.null(file$allfilters)) {
    file$allfilters <- paste("Selected Filters:", appliedfilter)
  } else {
    file$allfilters <- paste(file$allfilters, "&", appliedfilter)
  }
 })

# Print out filter variables in global object
output$selectedfilters <- renderText({
  filteroutput <- file$allfilters
  print(filteroutput)
  return(filteroutput)
})
```

2) The error is in the content function you pass to `downloadHandler`. The parameter is called `file`, which shadows the `file` `reactiveValues`. This works:

```
  ## Save out case data file
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(filetarget) {
      write.csv(file$dfSource, filetarget)
    }
  )
```

PS ad 1: It might be better to store the filters, instead of storing the filtered data frame and a string listing the filters. If your users change their mind, they have to start over from the beginning, but if you store the filters you can have a table or similar that allows deleting/editing individual filters. You could just store a list of two-element vectors, then iterate though the list to filter the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply- you are right on downloaderHandler with file, I didn't catch that reference.  On your comment about scoping, I agree with the complexity.  However, from what I understand, creating  a global variable allows one to save history of choices,  I believe your version only saves last choice.  If I can't render history of all choices given current application with global variable, I like your idea of storing all the filters and applying them at one time instead of iterating each separately and trying to store the text and filtered data.

Comment: No, you can save whatever you want in the `reactiveValue`, including a list. If I'm not mistaken, the only reason to use `<<-` in shiny if is you want to make something available to all users, so that one user's filter history would overwrite that for other users. In this case, we edit and store the string that contains the history, it stays around until you overwrite it; also, you use the same way to store and update the filtered data already and it works there. I've tested it with your minimal example, try it.